# How to count non-empty vector in a vector recursive type

Tags: c++, stl, c++98

I have a type that can be define as a vector of vector of vector ... of vector of an integral type. Example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector< std::vector<signed char> > > > > _data;
```

I'm searching for an elegant way to determine the number of non-empty vector at the deeper level. I could do that for that example using a 4 encapsulate loop like

```
for (it0 = data.cbegin() ; it0 != _data.cend() ; ++it0)
 for (it1 = *it0.cbegin() ; it1 != *it0.cend() ; ++it1)
   for (it2 = *it1.cbegin() ; it2 != *it1.cend() ; ++it2)
      for (it3 = *it2.cbegin() ; it3 != *it2.cend() ; ++it3)
          nonEmpty += (unsigned int) (*it3.empty());
```

But how can I create a template (to support vector, list or any kind of container sharing the same API) function to do that for any deep (more than 4 level) ? I think a recursion is the correct way, but don't know how to do that with Template ...

All help & advice will be welcome because I quite sure that there is more than one solution to that.

Comment: Is C++11 allowed for a solution?

Comment: No that a part of the problem, C++98 only !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a C++98 solution using nothing more than basic template specialization:

```
template<typename T> struct VectorCounter {
    /* no count method: this is an error */
};

template<typename U> struct VectorCounter<vector<U> > {
    static int count(const vector<U> &v) {
        return (int)v.empty();
    }
};

template<typename V> struct VectorCounter<vector<vector<V> > > {
    static int count(const vector<vector<V> > &v) {
        int ret = 0;
        for(typename vector<vector<V> >::const_iterator it=v.cbegin(); it!=v.cend(); ++it) {
            ret += VectorCounter<vector<V> >::count(*it);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};

template<typename T> int count_nonempty_vectors(const T &v) {
    return VectorCounter<T>::count(v);
}
```

Tested with the following (this test code uses `auto` as an extension because I'm lazy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

typedef vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<signed char> > > > > data_t;

int count_fixed(const data_t &data) {
    int nonEmpty = 0;
    for (auto it0 = data.cbegin() ; it0 != data.cend() ; ++it0)
        for (auto it1 = it0->cbegin() ; it1 != it0->cend() ; ++it1)
            for (auto it2 = it1->cbegin() ; it2 != it1->cend() ; ++it2)
                for (auto it3 = it2->cbegin() ; it3 != it2->cend() ; ++it3)
                    nonEmpty += (unsigned int)(it3->empty());
    return nonEmpty;
}

data_t build_data() {
    data_t data(5);
    int sz = 0;
    for (auto it0 = data.begin() ; it0 != data.end() ; ++it0) {
        it0->resize(4);
        for (auto it1 = it0->begin() ; it1 != it0->end() ; ++it1) {
            it1->resize(3);
            for (auto it2 = it1->begin() ; it2 != it1->end() ; ++it2) {
                it2->resize(2);
                it2->at(0).resize(1);
                it2->at(1).resize(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << count_fixed(build_data()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << count_nonempty_vectors(build_data()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Both print out "60".

Comment: I used that solution, mainly because it works for C++98 and even if I had to switch 'empty()' to '!empty()' :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Something like that ? (it uses `std::enable_if` so it's a C++11 answer, but maybe you can use the boost one instead).

```
template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename U::value_type,T>::value,std::size_t>::type
non_empties(const U& r)
{
    return !r.empty();
}

template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<typename U::value_type,T>::value,std::size_t>::type
non_empties(const U& r)
{
    std::size_t res = 0;
    for(auto& it : r)
    {
        res += non_empties<T>(it);
    }
    return res;
}
```

usage :

```
auto non_empty_terminal = non_empties<signed char>(_data);
```

You have to put the 'stop' type as a template parameter, so maybe it's not ideal.

Live exemple [here](http://ideone.com/nKhPyF)

Comment: thank it s a really nice code and I think I need to read it many times to fully understand how it works but as far as I know it should work for any container for which the empty api exist so deque list etc http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/ so why do you say it only work for vector ?

Comment: Well yeah it should work for every continer with a value_type field, but value_type for a std::map for example is a pair, so you'll have to put T = std::pair<...>, this is not really straightforward.

Comment: @alexbuisson Yes, works well with other STL container types, such as `std::set` and `std::deque`, added tests in the Live Exemple link.

Comment: hi, don't check your answer even if it's a perfectly valid way a,d at the beginning I though that with boost/utilities I could port that C++11 code to back in the old age using a C++98 compiler, but I failed... But this good work really well and it demonstrate how C++11 is powerfull!

Answer (score 0):

You can do pattern matching to count depthness

```
template <typename Base>
struct NestedVectors //non vector match
{
   static const size_t depth=0;
   static size_t count_empty(const Base& b)
   {
      throw std::string("cant be here");
    }

};

template <class Rv>
struct NestedVectors<std::vector<Rv> >
{
   static const size_t depth=1 + NestedVectors<Rv>::depth ;
   static size_t count_empty(const std::vector<Rv>& vec)
   {
       size_t r=0;
       if(NestedVectors<Rv>::depth == 0)
       {
            if(vec.empty())
                return 1;
       }
       else
       {
           for(size_t i =0; i < vec.size() ; ++i)
           {
               r+=NestedVectors<Rv>::count_empty(vec[i]);
           }
       }
       return r;
   }
};
int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<
       std::vector<
         std::vector<
           std::vector<
             std::vector<
               signed char
        > > > > > data_t;
   data_t t;
   std::cout << NestedVectors<data_t>::depth << " " << NestedVectors<data_t>::count_empty(t);
}
```

Comment: even it that code is really good the question was to count the number of non empty container at the deepest level. but thanks

Comment: @alexbuisson this should work, i havent tested much, just that compiles